2FA Authentication Fails When Logging into GitHub on a New Device
I was using two-factor authentication (2FA) on GitHub with my laptop, and everything was working fine. However, when I try to sign in on a different laptop, after entering my username and password, I get the following error: "Two-factor authentication failed."
I'm using the same 2FA app that I used on my original device, but it still fails. I’ve checked that I’m entering the code correctly. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it?
I expected the 2FA code from my authenticator app to work as it did on my original laptop, allowing me to successfully log into my GitHub account on the new device.
